# Can a local variable be accessed by the rest of the program OR Is it possible to load a hashtable without using malloc

Tags: c, hashtable

This is my program

```
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node* next; 
}
node;

static node* hashtable[MAX] = {NULL};
```

Then some code which is irrelevant. The main function calls a function load

```
bool load(const char* file_dic)
{

    FILE* file = fopen(file_dic, "r");
    char word[LENGTH+1];
    while ( (fscanf(file,"%s",word)) != EOF)
    {
         int value = hashf(word);
         if(hashtable[value] == NULL)
         {
             hashtable[value] = malloc (sizeof(node));
             strcpy(hashtable[value]-> word,word);
             hashtable[value]-> next = NULL; 
         }
         // more code
    }
}
```

The function load essentially load every word in file_dic in the hashtable.

Is it possible to load words in the hashtable without using the malloc function in such a manner that words remain accessible throughout the program

Comment: if you use a hash table you need to use malloc.

Comment: Requires probably because it is necessary to extend when a collision of the hash key is generated.

Comment: Just remove the `*` after `struct node* hastable`. Why you do not want to use malloc?

Comment: Minor: 1) suggest `hashtable[value] = malloc(sizeof(*hashtable[value]));`.  IMO, less error prone and easier to maintain. 2) Use `fgets()` vs. `fscanf(file,"%s",word)` which has no guard against too much input.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a non-detailed answer too long for a comment. Combining all below, you could achieve a hash table with as little as zero mallocs, though that's not realistic. But taking a more reasonable route, you could reduce your mallocs to about one per hash table bucket.

First of all, you could just read the entire file to memory and use just one malloc for the data (simple way: get size of file, malloc memory, read that much data). Then scan the read file, find starts of words and replace whitespace with `'/0'` bytes. As a bonus, this removes your `LENGHT` limitation on word length.

Extreme, unpractical version: If you are ok with your strings not being NUL-terminated C strings, then you could `mmap` the file. But since you probably don't want to change the file, the words would either need to store length or use whitespace as string terminator, neither of which is very convenient with C string functions. And of course someone editing the file while it's being used would break your table.

---

But you still need the list of words in one hash bucket, so above alone does not decrease number of mallocs, you need to get rid of the linked list. You could replace the linked list (one malloc per word) with [a dynamic array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array) (zero mallocs for empty bucket, one malloc for bucket with words).

Extreme, unpractical version (wastes total memory, risks failing inserts on full buckets): make the word list in each bucket be a fixed size array...

---

Finally, if you don't need rehashing, change your hashtable to be just

`static node hashtable[MAX]; // fixed size hashtable array`

or use a single malloc to allow dynamic size with:

```
static node *hashtable; // pointer to dynamically allocated hash table array
static size_t hashtable_size; // current size of hashtable
```

Comment: +1 for re-sizable table with `size_t hashtable_size`  (Minor: Both `hashtable hashtable_size` should be `static` or not)